# sklearn Logistic Regression setting penalty to none does not make C parameter irrelevant?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I want to create a logistic regression model object that has no penalty.

I have the below code. My understanding is that setting penalty to None will make C irrelevant. C is still 1 in this case. Why?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression(penalty = None, random_state = 0, max_iter = 1000)
clf.C
# 1.0
```

Comment: C still has a (default) value, but it _is_ (or should be) irrelevant.